# Jenkins , VSPhere plugin: how to clone a VM to a specific folder

Tags: jenkins-plugins, vsphere

I'm using Jenkins with VSPhere plugin to clone a VM from existing VM/template. I'm interested to clone this VM to a folder, different from the folde of the existing VM. In which field should I add the path to this folder? 
Tnx to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, 
After some research, it comes out, that there is a bug in VSphere plugin, and it's not possible to do so using it. 
But, there is a python library, called pyvmomi - it's pretty flexible and it gives this possibility.